# 'str' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to get some tweets using Tweepy library, but I am receiving this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'
```

I used this same code some months back and I didn't encounter this error, I don't know why I am receiving this.

Here is the code:

```
def tweets_mining(csv_file, search_query, num_tweets):
    with open(csv_file, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as file:
        thewriter = writer(file)
        header = ['tweet_id', 'time_created', 'tweet', 'location', 'retweets', 'likes']
        thewriter.writerow(header)

        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
                                   q=search_query,
                                   tweet_mode="extended",
                                   result_type="recent",
                                   lang="en").items(num_tweets):
            tweet_id = tweet.id
            time_created = tweet.created_at
            tweet = tweet.full_text
            location = tweet.user.location
            retweets = tweet.retweet_count
            likes = tweet.favorite_count
            row = [tweet_id, time_created, tweet, location, retweets, likes]
            thewriter.writerow(row)

search_term = "first search"

search_query = search_term + " -filter:links AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies"

tweets_mining('first_search.csv', search_query, 10)
```

This is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7884/2036184101.py in <module>
      3 search_query = search_term + " -filter:links AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies"
      4 
----> 5 tweets_mining('first_search.csv', search_query, 10)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7884/1256763917.py in tweets_mining(csv_file, search_query, num_tweets)
     13             time_created = tweet.created_at
     14             tweet = tweet.full_text
---> 15             location = tweet.user.location
     16             retweets = tweet.retweet_count
     17             likes = tweet.favorite_count

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: please provide that code

Comment: I already added the screenshots

Comment: how do i copy that code from image please provide in question in format of code

Comment: Please copy paste the code as text in your question

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Please, next time, extract a [mcve]. Also, find a video tutorial that shows how to step through code with a debugger. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please pay attention to the line `tweet = tweet.full_text`. This line is overriding your `tweet` variable to string. Try using different variable name.

Comment: I completely missed that, thanks for helping out.